# issue with datetime.strptime python

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime, strptime

This is my code:

```
import datetime
t1 = "Fri 11 Feb 2078 00:05:21"
t2 = "Mon 29 Dec 2064 03:33:48"
t3 = "Sat 02 May 2015 19:54:36"
t3_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(t3,"%a %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S")

print("debug")

t2_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(t2,"%a %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S")
t1_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(t1,"%a %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

**error:**
**ValueError**: *time data 'Mon 29 Dec 2064 03:33:48' does not match format '%a %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S'*

Why **t3** is getting parsed properly whereas **t1** and **t2** not getting parsed properly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the full name of the month in your input

this should work

```
import datetime

t1 = "Fri 11 February 2078 00:05:21"
t2 = "Mon 29 December 2064 03:33:48"
t3 = "Sat 02 May 2015 19:54:36"   

print("debug")

t1_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(t1,"%a %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S")
t2_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(t2,"%a %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S")
t3_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(t3,"%a %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Or just use %b instead of %B

```
import datetime

t1 = "Fri 11 Feb 2078 00:05:21"
t2 = "Mon 29 Dec 2064 03:33:48"
t3 = "Sat 02 May 2015 19:54:36"   

print("debug")

t1_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(t1,"%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
t2_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(t2,"%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
t3_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(t3,"%a %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

---

note that adding a textual day in your input won't change anything

for example

```
t4 = "Fri 02 May 2015 19:54:36"
t4_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(t4,"%a %d %B %Y %H:%M:%S")
print(t3_time == t4_time)
```

should return `True`

Comment: Alternatively, one could also use `%b` instead of `%B`. The important part is not to mix full and abbreviated month name.

Comment: It worked perfectly. 'May' has 3 letter. I got confused with Dec and Feb. I was wondering what was wrong. Anyways, it worked. Thanks a lot. :)